# python why empty list creation is not working without range and len functions in for loop

Tags: python, list

This below python code is working fine:

```py
my_list = [10, 1, 8, 3, 5]
total = 0
for i in my_list:   # list without range and len function
    total += i
print(total)
```

---

But below revised code is not working in for loop without using range and len func, why?

```py
my_list = []
total = 0

lower_range = 1
upper_range = 11
for i in range(lower_range,upper_range):
    my_list.append(4*i)

print(my_list)
print(len(my_list))

for i in my_list:  # Error is giving index out of range**
    total = total + my_list[i]

print(total)
```

---

However, if I re-write as below it works fine:

```py
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    total = total + my_list[i]
```

Question is why in this case without using range() and len() for loop is not working for lists?

Comment: Just replace `total = total + my_list[i]` with `total = total + i` in the first loop. Using `for i in my_list`, you're directly accessing its elements.

Answer (score 1):

It shows the `list index out of range` because i = 40 and list should have 41 items for it to work. As list has less items than it shows the error.
So you need to add len because len is the lenght of list which is equal to the items in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in my_list:  # Error is giving index out of range**
     total = total + my_list[i]
```

In this for loop, i represents an object in the List. NOT an index.

It is solved in your re-write because i now represents an index.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Well when you iterate through a list like

```
for i in [100,200,300]:
    print(i)
```

your going to get the output `100,200,300`. Therefor you cannot use `i` to index a list. `mylist[300]`. So in your example, i'd assume you just want to add all the numbers to `total`.

```
for i in my_list:  # Error is NOT giving index out of range
    total += i
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
for i in my_list:  # Error is giving index out of range**
    total = total + my_list[i]
```

you are iterating over the *contents* of the list, not over its indexes, so `i` get assigned the values: `[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]`, as your list is indexed from 0 to 9 you get `index out of range` for values beyond this range. It happens on `12` on your case.

list contents may be any object, wheres list indexes are always zero based index: from `0` to `len(my_list)-1`.

It may get more clearer if you set the list contents to strings instead of integers. Also the pattern `range(len(my_list))` is so common that python has a special function for this: `enumerate()`, which allows you to iterate over both the list index *and* its values.

Rewriting your example:

```
my_list = []
total = ''

lower_range = 0
upper_range = 10
for i in range(lower_range, upper_range):
    my_list.append(chr(ord('A')+i))

print('my_list:', my_list)
print('length of my_list:', len(my_list))

for value in my_list:
    print('value:', value)

for i, value in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f"Item index <{i}> has value {value!r}")
    total = total + my_list[i]

print('total:', total)
```

Output:

```
my_list: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
length of my_list: 10
value: A
value: B
value: C
value: D
value: E
value: F
value: G
value: H
value: I
value: J
Item index <0> has value 'A'
Item index <1> has value 'B'
Item index <2> has value 'C'
Item index <3> has value 'D'
Item index <4> has value 'E'
Item index <5> has value 'F'
Item index <6> has value 'G'
Item index <7> has value 'H'
Item index <8> has value 'I'
Item index <9> has value 'J'
total: ABCDEFGHIJ
```

Comment: Great Fabiano. I understood my mistake. Thanks for your explanation. Thanks all for their clarifications.

Comment: @AminulIslam I see you are new to StackOverflow: If your question was answered properly, please do select one of the answers as your *Accepted Answer*, this way the question will stop being shown as *answered* to potential responders.